# Why doesn't QProcess kill,close, terminate calls the deconstructor of the process?

Tags: linux, qt

i have a watchdog stop function placed inside the deconstructor of the process that i executed from my C++ program. Everytime i close using the "X" button on that process QT GUI, it will run thru the codes that i placed in the deconstructor. but when i try to do a Qprocesskill/close/terminate to kill the process in my C++ program, the codes in the deconstructors(of the process) are not being executed. Anyone knows whats wrong or have alternative methods to close the process? Thanks!!!

Btw im on linux.

Comment: Show code or it didn't happen

Comment: @user Could you capitalize your question correctly - 'i'->'I", etc.

Comment: "kill" and "terminate" don't really sound like a graceful shutdown of your application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No objects get torn down when the process abruptly exits with those functions. They're the equivalent to the C function exit(1). Try gracefully exiting the event loop of your QApplication::exec by calling QApplication::quit () which will exit the main event loop inside of exec and allow main to exit normally and allowing all objects that would normally destroy themselves at that point to do so.

Comment: Actually, the "C" function `exit` does run destructors of static objects (well actually `atexit` handlers, but this is how static object's destructors are typically hooked up). Thus it is more the equivalent of `_exit()`. Of course that doesn't invalidate your answers moral: do a graceful exit of the loop :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use std::signal to register the handlers for those signals (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal):

```
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>

namespace
{
  volatile std::sig_atomic_t gSignalStatus;
}

void signal_handler(int signal)
{
  gSignalStatus = signal;
}

int main()
{
  // Install a signal handler
  std::signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

  std::cout << "SignalValue: " << gSignalStatus << '\n';
  std::cout << "Sending signal " << SIGINT << '\n';
  std::raise(SIGINT);
  std::cout << "SignalValue: " << gSignalStatus << '\n';
}
```